# What is the difference between BTC and Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, segwit2x

To my understanding BTC and bitcoin core are the same, when mentioned against S2X/B2X. Is that the case? (Bitcoin Core is BTC in the post segwit2x world?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitcoin Core is a specific implementation of the Bitcoin protocol, specifically the one in the [Bitcoin GitHub Repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin). It is the evolved version of the original client Satoshi wrote, in C++. It is also the reference implementation of Bitcoin.

But Bitcoin Core is not the only Bitcoin node software, there are others written in other programming languages and with other extra features, for example there is [bcoin](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin), [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) written in Go, [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/), [Bitcore](https://bitcore.io/), etc.

When being compared to S2X, Bitcoin Core is sometimes used to refer to the Bitcoin protocol defined by the Bitcoin Core reference implementation - i.e. Bitcoin itself, to avoid confusion. Bitcoin Core is also sometimes used to refer to the *developers of* Bitcoin Core, but it must be noted that Bitcoin Core is not an organisation, it is a piece of software.

Comment: Thank you @MeshCollinder ! But another question then, so does that mean that when I hold BTC currently, I have Bitcoin Core, or not?

Comment: You have Bitcoin. Bitcoin Core is just software which you can use to manage your bitcoins. You could store your bitcoins in any other wallet, then you would have bitcoins but not Bitcoin Core software